# Could not locate EntityFramework dll when publishing to Azure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, azure

I am trying to publish an MVC app and SQL Server DB to an Azure website.

Everything builds and loads fine when I run locally from within Visual Studio. However when trying to publish to Azure, I get 13 build errors which are all basically because the DLLs for EntityFramework cannot be found.

```
Warning 2   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.  RMoney.Data
Warning 3   Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework.SqlServer". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.    RMoney.Data
```

I have enabled the option to allow NuGet to download missing packages (I added EF via nuget).

I have set all DLLs to be 'copylocal=true' too.

I have published other Azure Websites without an attached SQL DB with no problems.

Any idea what I might have done wrong?

Comment: select **Project selected** from `Solution Explorer --> right-click on the solution/project --> Manage NuPackages` and rebuild

Comment: Going to 'Manage Packages' doesn't seem to have a 'rebuild' option. However I nuked my packages folder, nuget has downloaded everything again and same errors.

Comment: No, that is not what i asked to do... select **Project selected** from 'Solution Explorer --> Right-click on the Solution/Project --> Manage NuPackages' and **Re-Build** your **Solution / Project**

Comment: Clicking Manage NuPackages brings up the standard GUI for NuGet http://i.imgur.com/KY1TzJV.png. Are you saying do nothing with this window open? I cannot rebuild my solution without closing it again obviously.